# receive notifications when users connected an WIFI access point

Tags: android, wifi, access-point

I want to define a connection to my access point. I want receive notifications when users connected.
I know that I can query arp table(/proc/net/arp) , from which I can find connected users. Here is the sample code:

```
public static ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> result = null;

    try {
        result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            Log.d("Debug:line=", line);
            if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];

                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    result.add(new ClientScanResult(splitted[0], splitted[3], splitted[5]));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Question: is there any better way to do this, except viewing arp-table every n seconds?**

**UPD**: 
If you connect to an access point, and then disconnect, then the record will still be in the arp-table.That is, until I can not get a list of all connected users

Comment: Wifi state permission in manifest

Comment: @Boopathi. Yes.He was there

Comment: give permission for wifi in your application

Comment: @Boopathi '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>'

Answer (score 1):

You can add a BroadcastReciever to connection state. http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: And then I will be able to determine when connecting to my access point?

Comment: I found only one BroadcastReciever associated with an access point (WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION). And he only tracks the state of the access point, but I want state of connect to access point

Comment: It's a trigger for running your code... instead of running every few seconds

Comment: You could not explain? I catch this action?

Comment: I noticed that in a moment connect in the logs write I/hostapd﹕ wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 00:21:e9:dc:07:85

Comment: You can register a reciever to this action, and than execute your code to check if user is connected to your  access point

Comment: Here's the problem. I can not find the desired action